# How to authenticate through Google Cloud IAP with client from gapi (google-api-javascript-client) library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client, google-iap

Given a client-side app (written in Angular, but it's not much important) where I use [google-api-javascript-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) library to authenticate users. In a way described here - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js:

```
      gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        gapi.client.init({
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS
        }).then(() => {
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.onSigninStatusChanged.bind(this));
          const isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
          if (!isSignedIn) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({prompt: 'select_account'});
          }
        });
      });
```

Now I want to access a backend in AppEngine behind [Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP)](https://cloud.google.com/iap/).

I tried naively to pass a token from GoogleUser via http request's authorization header, but it doesn't seem to work (getting 401):

```
    let token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token;
    this.http.get<Config>('https://myservice-dot-myproject.ew.r.appspot.com/api/get',
      {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
      });
```

I guess I need somehow to use OAuth Client ID from IAP.
I found a [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/samples/idtokens-iap.js) on how to do it with nodejs auth client.
But can't find a way to do it with the client-side `google-api-javascript-client` lib.

**UPDATE**:
I found a nice online resource to verify token that I got from `GoogleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` - https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=token ([source](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint)), it display the following:

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "my OAuth Client ID that I used in gapi (CLIENT_ID)",
  "aud": "OAuth Client ID that I used in gapi (CLIENT_ID)",
  "sub": "user id (number)",
  "hd": "Google user GSuite domain",
  "email": "Google user email",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "at_hash": "some hash",
  "name": "Google user name",
  "picture": "an url",
  "given_name": "Google user firstname",
  "family_name": "Google user lastname
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": "1615972232",
  "exp": "1615975832",
  "jti": "87129b6c0f684b0bc7beac9df5e522e6272c13f1",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "6a8ba5652a7044121d4fedac8f14d14c54e4895b",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Comment: The most likely reason for the 401 is that the Identity Token `aud` (audience) is incorrect (from the wrong authentication system). Base64 decode the Identity Token and post in your question.

Comment: updated the question with token's details

Comment: which client_id do you use?

Comment: For authentication via gapi I used an OAuth client with Type="Web application" created specifically for authentication. But I also tried using the IAP's OAuth Client ID.